# send mail with personalized body

Tags: codeigniter

with codeigniter I send mail with personalized body.
all right except I can't retrieve ($name) and ($message) from the controller code. When I receive the email instead of Welcome Luigi I receive Welcome $name .... and as a message -> $message

controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->config('emailer');
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'Mymailer', 'upload', 'email'));
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file'));

public function index()
{
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        $name = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
        $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE); 
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject', TRUE); 
        $message = $this->input->post('message', TRUE); 
        $file = $this->input->post('file', TRUE);
        $path = APPPATH.'/tmp/';    
        $xmsg = $this->load->view('email_body','',TRUE);

        $this->mymailer->addAddress($email, $name);
        $this->mymailer->Subject=($subject);
        $this->mymailer->msgHTML($xmsg);
```

file application/views/email_body.php

```
        <td class="h2" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;" align="center">Welcome ' . $name . '</td>

    <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666; font-size: 14px;"></div>' . $message . '<br /><br />
```

please how can I do that when the email appears there is also the sender's name and message?

Comment: you need to echo the variable: `<?=$name?>`

Comment: no retrieve the variables ...... phpmailer output: Could not access file: 
2019-07-09 02:44:37 SERVER -> CLIENT:...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the name and message data to the

```
$data["name"] =  $name;
$data["message"] =  $message;
$xmsg = $this->load->view('email_body',$data,TRUE);
```

Then only the data will be replaced in the email_body.php